# Return all links from a google search

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

We just relaunched our website and I need to remove all of old links from googles index. I did a `site:ourdomain.com` search but I don't really feel like copying and pasting all of the links that way.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do a 301 redirect from any old URLs that have a corresponding URL in the relaunched website. This will allow Google, and your users, to find and associate the old pages with the new. This is important for SEO as it carries over any links you have pointing to the old URLs.
- Serve a 404 error for any pages that no longer exist and do not have a corresponding URL in the relaunched website. This will tell Google those pages are gone and to remove them from their index.
- Make a 404 page that tells users your site has been redesigned and try to point them towards the new pages. At the very least point to a sitemap and where they can ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching from xyz.com to abc.com, you could just use a 301 redirect and let google figure it out.  It takes a couple of days, but google will most likely re crawl your site afterwards.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't move my site, but we relaunched, so alot of pages don't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of time, when the google crawler decides to visit your new site. And maybe creating a sitemap for google would speed up the task. I think this link could help you too:

http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this Google page](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734) has the answer(s) you're looking for.

Comment: This is what I would use. I have about 250 links in google that I need to add. Is there something I can use to get all of these links automatically?

Comment: By adding a sitemap to your site (there are tools to auto-generate these), Google should crawl all your newly created pages the first time it crawls your site (usually a few days to a week in my experience)